# how can i add h3 code from asp.net behind code?

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, webforms

I want show a html code from "else", how can i?

this is my code

```
    if (output == "1")
    {

        Session["user"] = textuser.Text;
        Response.Redirect("~/Default2.aspx");
    }
    else
    {


        // show html code <h4  id='error1' runat ='server'></h4>
    }
```

Comment: Does it *have* to be done in the code-behind?  You can have a block with (for example) `<% if (true) { %> <h1><% } else {%><strong><% } %>` in the .asp file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add that control to the page, but with `Visible=false`

```
<h4 id="error1" runat="server" Visible="false"></h4>
```

And then you can just set make it visible from the code beside:

```
error1.Visible = true;
error1.InnerText = "Some message";
```

Comment: Cool @IgnacioGreyStark, remember to mark the answer as correct

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of ways to skin a cat, but one way is to add an [HtmlGenericControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlgenericcontrol(v=vs.110).aspx) to your WebForm, passing the appropriate tag ("h3" or "h4") to the constructor.